# Changing Height of ScrollViewer Content dynamically through code

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm stuck at a point where I have to change the height of scroll viewer content irrespective of the size the contents inside it need.

The reason is that I will have a very long Image and I don't want to slow my GUI while scrolling. So,I cut the long image and I render stitched images of it depending on current scrollviewer vertical offset.

I tried to achieve it by putting a Hidden Long image so that it won't render on scroll and there won't be any lag. But I don't feel good about it.

Can someone help me to dynamically increase the ScrollViewer content Height?

The code is here:

```
     <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Grid.RowSpan="12" Margin="10,60,10,0" >
    <Image x:Name="StitchedImage" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ImageScrollViewer" Background="Transparent" ScrollChanged="ImageScrollViewer_ScrollChanged" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
      <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <Image x:Name="longImageHidden" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid >
```

Comment: Give your grid inside the scrollviewer a name, then in codebehind manually set it's height whenever you want?

Comment: Then, the rendered height would not be equal to the rendered height when an image Height is set to the same value.

Comment: I think It would be really cool if I can just give a blank image specifing just height and width without any source. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

> I think It would be really cool if I can just give a blank image specifing just height and width without any source. Is that even possible?

Yes, it is:

```
<Image Height="1000" />
```

You could also set the `Height` of a `ScrollViewer` and any other `FrameworkElement` derived type.

Comment: Not the Height property of the image but the actual Pixel Height of the blank image.

Comment: That's just a matter of setting the Stretch property to None, isn't it?

Comment: I have to check it. But I need the image to stretch horizontally and fill the space. Will that work out when I say HorizontalAlignment=stretch and stretch=None?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: I removed the hidden Image and set height to grid. Thank you. It is not the solution but I had to adjust with it.